# Why is this code snippet showing a compilation error?

Tags: java, compiler-errors

I am getting this compilation issue, and I'm not able to figure out why. Can someone help?

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int n = scan.getInt() ;
    System.out.println(factorial(n)) ;


int factorial(int a){
        if (a==0) 
            return 1;
        else 
            return (a*factorial(a-1));
    }}
```

**Post Edit Note**: I wasn't aware of the fact that another function can't be declared inside main(). On writing it outside, it worked fine.

Comment: It's missing a `}` after the `System.out.println` line. And there's one `}` too many at the end.

Comment: You forgot to close your `main()` method with a `}` bracket.  Most likely, you pasted `factorial` inside `main`.

Comment: Yeah, realised the mistake. I didn't know that another function couldn't be declared inside main(). Thank you for the help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're trying to create a method called `factorial` *inside* your `main` method. It has to be next to it, not inside it.

Formatting your code readably and consistently helps make the problem clear:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.math.*;
import java.util.regex.*;

public class Solution {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = scan.getInt();
        System.out.println(factorial(n));

        int factorial(int a) {                  // <=== Problem
            if (a == 0)
                return 0;
            else
                return (a * factorial(a - 1));
        }
    }
}
```

Instead:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.math.*;
import java.util.regex.*;

public class Solution {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = scan.getInt();
        System.out.println(factorial(n));
    }

    int factorial(int a) {
        if (a == 0)
            return 0;
        else
            return (a * factorial(a - 1));
    }
}
```

The above still has a problem (`factorial` needs to be `static`, or you need to create an instance to call it on), but it's in the right place now.

Comment: Thank you, it seems to work now. Out of curiosity, why can't you define another function inside main()?

Comment: @AmbareeshSJ: It's just not how Java is designed. You could have a lambda, or an instance of an anonymous class, both of which work a bit like a nested method, but you can't define an actual nested method.

Comment: Can you explain the static part? Why does making factorial static make it work, and not otherwise. Is it similar to static variables (where the variable kind of remembers the previous value and then proceeds?)

Comment: @AmbareeshSJ: Just refer to your Java book or a tutorial website, searching for the difference between static and instance methods.

Comment: @jackjay: No, if that were true we'd have a problem. Static methods can call instance methods -- they just need to have an instance to call them on. :-)

Comment: i was telling for the direct call without instance, Thankyou

Comment: Got it @T.J.Crowder